# How to interpolate one image matrix into another one?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, interpolation, reshape

I've got two image matrices. Both contain radar information about the same area, with different units and values. But, these circles are not fit onto each other. One is like it's zoomed in. I would like to do some element operations in these matrices.

[image]

Let's say there is a value in matrix A which is located in `A[100, 50]`, but its element wise associate value is `B[95, 45]`. However, still I don't know which value is associated with which one in each matrix. This is only an example.

Matrix A shape is `(720, 720)` a circle that inside the circle there are values.
Matrix B's shape is the same, but the circle is a little bit zoomed in and the edges are not completely round in some areas due to not fitting in edges of the matrix square!

How can I reshape(interpolate?) one matrix into another?

Comment: Two pictures might help.

Comment: Thnx! I added a photo